# Twitter Bootstrap class dropdown-menu background too short

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling to figure something out. We have a dropdown menu on our site with five elements and a slight gradient fill background. I need to add a sixth element but it appears below the dropdown menu back ground. So it is outside of the gradient fill back ground.

The menu is the tools menu on the following page http://stats.feathercoin.com/

If you use inspect element and add another

menu item so can see it is outside of the rest. The original web developer has gone and I cannot figure this one out. The code looks simple enough so I believe this is a customisation that I cannot unravel.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="//www.feathercoin.com/buttongen">Button Generator</a></li>
    <li><a href="//www.feathercoin.com/calc">Calculator</a></li>
    <li><a href="//www.feathercoin.com/charts">Charts</a></li>
    <li><a href="//explorer.feathercoin.com/">Explorer</a></li>
    <li><a href="//local.feathercoin.com/">Local Feathercoin</a></li>
    <li><a href="//www.feathercoin.com/netstats/">Stats</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope that this makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Done. http://jsfiddle.net/UhXXF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an higher value for `max-height` of `.navbar .nav>li>a:hover ~ .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu:hover`

Like:

```
.navbar .nav>li>a:hover ~ .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu:hover {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-top: 0;
  max-height: 500px;
  -moz-transition: max-height .5s, padding 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s, padding 0.2s;
  -o-transition: max-height .5s, padding 0.2s;
  transition: max-height .5s, padding 0.2s;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AU3rr/

Comment: Thanks for that. It has inadvertently fixed another glitch with that menu.